# android - addind ad disturbing the whole layout

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I've made a memory game for android. The game is made of a `TableLayout`, with `TableRow`s with a custom view called `Card`, added dynamically. The card can resize themselves according to the screen size.

The problem is that when I added a `com.google.ads.AdView`, I got troubles: when the ad loaded, the tableLayout became smaller, but the `Card`s doesn't resize themselves, and being 'cut' from too little space.

What I tried:
adding in `onCreate`:

```
    myAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceivedAd");
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_TableLayout_id);
            tl.invalidate();
        }
        ...
    });
```

I tried also to loop throug all the cards and make call to `tl.recomputeViewAttributes(View);`, and both didn't solve the problem.

`OnSizeChaneged` of the cards didn't have even called, so it useless.

So, the question is: How can I make the TableLayout recompute the space for each element while resizing?